# System.UnauthorizedAccessException when trying to upload a file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to download a file from my computer in the localhost. But I keep getting the error

 
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'c:\users\zunair\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\Uploads' is denied.

Here is my code

```
if (FileExt == ".pdf")
{
    Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=FileName");
    Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads" + FileName));
    Response.End();
}
```

I get the error at `Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads" + FileName));`

Comment: You need to make sure that the IIS account that your app pool runs under has security permissions for the directory.

Comment: This question gets asked a lot. Here's another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037524/system-unauthorizedaccessexception-on-a-simple-asp-net-file-io-operations

Comment: How do I give the required permissions to IIS?

Comment: The same way you give permissions to anyone else. Right click on the directory and add it on the security tab. You'll need to look at the pool to see what account it's running under.

Comment: hi i have this same issue and have given permissions to my user, Network Service, IUSR on windows 10 iis 10 but its still not working